# Any way to take the preceding element?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div id="TheDivIWantTheBelowScriptToAddress"></div>
<script>
    document.getPreviousDiv().innerHTML = "YADDA"
</script>
```

Now I know that in JS I can easily reference an element by its ID like `document.getElementById("blah")`.

However, when the page is being generated from templates, it sometimes might get tricky to ensure that the ids won't repeat. It would be more convenient if I could just reference `the first element of a given type (like div or canvas) that lies before the script tag in which this script is included`.

Can this be somehow done or do I have to write extra logic to ensure the uniqueness of divs?

Comment: I suspect that this issue can be avoided completely by having the script inject its own `div` element and manipulating its content.

Comment: @Boaz How so, because even if I do it, I'll have to have to find the element to which I can append the script's own `div` element, and suddenly the question becomes recursive...

Comment: Take a look at [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

Comment: @Boaz Thanks, with catbadger's answer this should work

Answer (score 5):

I should use this:

```
<div></div>
<script>
    document.currentScript.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = "blah";
</script>
```

The `currentScript` gets the current script element.

The `previousElementSibling` gets the previous element.

Comment: Use `.previousElementSibling`. The `.previousSibling` could be a `#text` node

Comment: I'm not entirely certain why is `previousSibling` duplicated here?

Comment: @gaazkam Because the first `previousSibling` returns the `Text` (the line break) between the `<div>` and the `<script>`. The second one returns the `<div>`. That’s why `previousSibling` is not appropriate here and you should use `previousElementSibling`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for .prev

```
$('selector').prev()
```

EDIT: and again without jquery:

```
var x = document.getElementById("item2").previousSibling.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Note that the question does not have the `jQuery` tag.

Comment: Fine - so first I have to find this `item2` element - and how can I reference from a `script` tag this `script` tag where the code being executed resides?

Comment: All right, thanks, I guess this should work: `document.currentScript.previousSibling`

Comment: Use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) instead of `previousSibling`.